# Point Clustering algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, cluster-computing, complexity-theory

I need help to solve a geometry problem .
Consider a set of points.
We note the number of points N.

We note d the euclidienne distance and dmax a value.

Two points p1 and p2 are connected if and only if the distance d(p1,p2)<dmax.

The problem is to create an algorithm that returns a list of the size of connected components.

For example in the figure below the algorithm should return

[3, 2, 4, 1]

I drawed the connections in red but initially we only have the points (here in black). If needed the program should calculate all the connections.
[figure below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTTRc.jpg)

I have two algorithm one iterative and the other recursive. I used a DBScan. But it is not fast enough. Yhe complexity is O(N^2)

I need it to be faster with if possible an O(N) or O(N*log(N)).

I read about DFS but i am not really sure...

Thanks for help

Comment: You can try to use k-d tree to find the closest point for each point. By doing this you can eliminate calculating of distances between points that are far apart.

Comment: That is a nice way of optimization. However i updated the question by adding that i would like not to download any module on my pc (sorry i forgot to mention :\ ).

Answer (score 3):

Use SciPy (or another library) to find the [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) of the input points (which contains the minimum spanning tree, which includes enough edges to make the rest of this answer work). Delete the edges of the triangulation that have length ≥ dmax. Find the connected components of the remaining edges.

This is O(n log n), with the inner loop in Qhull (a compiled extension).

(k-d tree or other locality structures offer another path to a solution, but the worst case is likely ω(n log n) if there are many pairs of points within dmax of each other.)

Comment: I will look into that and try it. I will come back here to tell you the results. However it will take sometime so i can fully understand the concepts :)

Comment: Yeah and if this works with scipy i will try to code myself the delaunay function too instead of importing it from scipy :)))

Comment: @Wil123 the Delaunay triangulation contains every edge in the minimum spanning tree. The minimum spanning tree has the property that, for every omitted edge, the cycle formed by that edge with edges in the minimum spanning tree has no edge longer than the omitted edge. Therefore if there is a path where every edge has length length than dmax, there is a path with this property that uses only edges in the minimum spanning tree. Use depth-first search to find the connected components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will study that more deeply. I feel like i am really close to a super fast algorithm :))))